# How to run functions from a dict of functions while specifying *args or **kwargs

Tags: python, function, dictionary, python-asyncio

I basically want to run tasks that are gathered from a dict of functions. I'm using asyncio in my program but it probably doesn't matter for my question. Here is my code to illustrate...

```
import asyncio
import random


async def faketask(taskname):    # This is a function to simulate asynchronous tasks being performed.
    fakedelay = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f'{taskname} started (completing in {fakedelay} seconds)')
    await asyncio.sleep(fakedelay)
    print(f'{taskname} completed after {fakedelay} seconds')


async def main():
    tasklist = {    # This is a dict of tasks to be performed
    'Task-1': faketask,
    'Task-2': faketask,
    'Task-3': faketask,
    }

    _tasks = []
    for taskname in tasklist:
        _tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(tasklist[taskname](taskname)))
        print(f'Added {taskname} to job queue.')
    await asyncio.gather(*_tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

This works pretty well. But I want to repeat certain tasks periodically, so I added some code to the `faketask` function.

```
async def faketask(taskname, interval=None):
    fakedelay = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f'{taskname} started (completing in {fakedelay} seconds)')
    await asyncio.sleep(fakedelay)
    print(f'{taskname} completed after {fakedelay} seconds')
    if interval is not None:
        print(f'Repeating {taskname} in {interval} seconds')
        while True:
            await faketask(taskname, *args, **kwargs)
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

This makes the function repeat by providing the kwarg `interval` with an integer. Future functions may also use additional *args and **kwargs.

So I basically wish I could specify the repeat interval in the tasklist dict, e.g.

```
    tasklist = {
    'Task-1': faketask,
    'Task-2': faketask,
    'Task-3': faketask(interval=60),
    }
```

But that doesn't work because *faketask() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'taskname'.*

Is there any clever way to solve this?

And as a bonus question, the line `_tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(tasklist[taskname](taskname)))` looks a bit ugly, is there any way to pass the `taskname` argument automatically?

Comment: when you pass `Task-1: faketask` you populate that dictionary with a function object. when you do `Task-3:faketask(interval=60)` you populate the value with the result of that function, but that function is expecting to get a function object as the fisrt parameter, and you havnt given it. thats why it fails

Comment: @NotSoShabby I think I can see why it fails but I'm not sure how to go about making it work as I want it to

Comment: Try: `asyncio.gather(*[faketask(taskname, interval) for interval in [40, 50, 60]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which is designed exactly for situations like this:

```
'Task-3': functools.partial(faketask, interval=60),
```

> And as a bonus question, the line `_tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(tasklist[taskname](taskname)))` looks a bit ugly, is there any way to pass the taskname argument automatically?

You can use `items()` to remove the redundancy:

```
tasks = []
for taskname, taskfn in tasklist.items():
    tasks.append(taskfn(taskname))
```

The explicit call to `asyncio.ensure_future` is unnecessary because `asyncio.gather` does that automatically. Also, I've renamed `_tasks` to just `tasks`. By convention, the `_` in front of a variable name denotes that the variable will not be used in subsequent code, which is not the case here.

Comment: This seems to fix it, thank you! Am also grateful for the info regarding ```asyncio.gather``` and ```_``` too. Unfortunately I'm now seeing that the functionality to repeat the function doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @noob It seems like it should work, you just need to actually declare the `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters before using them.