# Passing *args and **kwargs to an asyncio periodic wrapper function from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio to gather tasks from a dictionary and execute them but I'm having difficulty getting it to work as intended. *(This is sort of a follow-up question to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559283/how-to-run-functions-from-a-dict-of-functions-while-specifying-args-or-kwargs) but I re-wrote the code a bit because it didn't work as intended and decided it would be better to use a wrapper function instead.)*

So I'm using a wrapper to call the specified task function. I want the wrapper to forward any *args or **kwargs to the task function, and also repeat the task peridiocally if the `interval` kwarg is set.

How do I pass this information to the wrapper and the task function, while keeping it easily maintainable with the ability to easily add new tasks to the `tasks` dictionary?

Please take a look at my code for illustration.

```
import asyncio
import random

async def run_task(taskname, taskfunc, interval=None, *args, **kwargs):
    # Wrapper which will run the specified function, and repeat it if 'interval' is set.
    # Should also be able to pass any potential *args and **kwargs to the function.
    fakedelay = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f'{taskname} started (completing in {fakedelay} seconds)')
    await taskfunc(fakedelay, *args, **kwargs)
    print(f'{taskname} completed after {fakedelay} seconds')
    if interval is not None:
        print(f'Repeating {taskname} in {interval} seconds...')
        while True:
            await taskfunc(fakedelay, *args, **kwargs)
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)

async def faketask(fakedelay, *args, **kwargs):
    # Function to simulate a coroutine task
    await asyncio.sleep(fakedelay)

async def main():
    tasks = {
        # Dictionary of tasks to perform
        'Task-1': faketask,
        'Task-2': faketask,
        'Task-3': faketask,
    }

    tasklist = []
    for taskname, taskfunc in tasks.items():
        tasklist.append(run_task(taskname, taskfunc))
        print(f'Added {taskname} to job queue.')
    await asyncio.gather(*tasklist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

This seems to work well so far. But let's say that I want Task-3 to repeat every 10 seconds *after each time it completes.* I would like to simply specify it in the `tasks` dictionary, to make it as simple as possible to add new tasks in the future. E.g. like this:

```
tasks = {
    # Dictionary of tasks to perform
    'Task-1': faketask,
    'Task-2': faketask,
    'Task-3': faketask(interval=10),
}
```

But running this gives
`TypeError: faketask() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fakedelay'` I suppose it makes sense because the `interval` kwarg is meant for the wrapper and not the task function (`faketask`) itself. And the wrapper doesn't seem able to add any *args or **kwargs (`fakedelay` in this situation).

In my previous question I was given the suggestion to use `functools.partial`.

```
tasks = {
    'Task-1': faketask,
    'Task-2': faketask,
    'Task-3': functools.partial(faketask, interval=10),
}
```

It solved the issue from my previous question somewhat but after re-writing the code and adding a wrapper function, it seemingly does nothing now, and admittedly I'm having difficulty understanding how `functools.partial` is meant to be used.

So my questions are,

1. How can I go about this, is this the appropriate way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
2. How can I provide *args and **kwargs to a specific function in the `tasks` dictionary, in as simple of a way as possible (so new tasks can be easily added), and have them forwarded to the task function itself via the wrapper?
3. Is my method of repeating a function periodically correct? I specifically want it to only sleep *after completion* before starting again, and not just fire off again even if the last instance hasn't finished yet.

Comment: *after re-writing the code and adding a wrapper function, it seemingly does nothing now* - please show the re-written code. The question is long, but it doesn't actually include the code that is failing!

Comment: @user4815162342 My apologies for the lack of clarity. The code that I posted here is the (slightly) re-written code including the new wrapper function ```run_task```, which is supposed to launch the task functions specified in the ```tasks``` dictionary. I want to make some of the functions repeat periodically by specifying a number of seconds with the ```interval``` kwarg. This is not working. The code that is "failing" is the main code block and ```'Task-3': faketask(interval=10)```, which is there to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user4815162342 Wrapping it in ```functools.partial``` does seemingly nothing. I want Task-3 to repeat but the program just exits.

Comment: In your original question `interval` was supposed to be an optional argument to `faketask`, which is why I recommended `partial`. Here you want to specify optional arguments to `run_task`, so `partial` doesn't help.

Comment: @user4815162342 I understand this is a different situation and that is why I posted this as a new question. Perhaps ```partial``` isn't the solution here, but what is? I'm asking for help on how to go about this

Comment: You can specify additional options for `run_task` alongside the function to execute. For example, instead of `'Task-3': faketask(interval=10),`, use `'Task-3': (faketask, {'interval': 10}),`. When looping over the dictionary items, unpack the tuple as `(taskfunc, run_options)` and invoke `run_task(taskname, taskfunc, **run_options)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly but I tried ```for taskname, (taskfunc, run_options) in tasks.items():``` and that gave a ```TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object```

Comment: You need to either specify all of them as tuples, or have an `if` that checks which variant you got, [like this](https://pastebin.com/zQgy17fM).

Comment: @user4815162342 This did the trick! But it seems the task won't repeat, which is a bit strange because that part should work. It does print the string to indicate it will repeat in 10 seconds but after that nothing happens. Anyway, huge thanks for your help, I'm very happy the ```interval``` functionality is finally working! If you'd like you can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one

Comment: Correction: the function does repeat, it's only the printed message that doesn't show

Comment: Isn't that because the printed message is not included in the loop, but outside (before) it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I had to debug with print() to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `functools.partial` only makes sense if you are actually wrapping `faketask` to include an optional keyword argument. If you need to apply the keyword argument to a different function (`run_task`), then you need to do so independently. For example, you could specify additional optoins for `run_task` in the `tasks` dict:

```
tasks = {
    'Task-1': faketask,
    'Task-2': faketask,
    'Task-3': (faketask, {'interval': 10)),
}
```

The code that invokes `run_task` will then need to recognize the tuples:

```
for taskname, taskfunc_maybe_with_options in tasks.items():
    if isinstance(taskfunc_maybe_with_options, tuple):
        taskfunc, options = taskfunc_maybe_with_options
    else:
        taskfunc = taskfunc_maybe_with_options
        options = {}
    tasklist.append(run_task(taskname, taskfunc, **options))
```